# Passing array of strings to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, visual-c++, c++14

I am trying to create a program that uses class, arrays, and functions to show information about two students(Name, id#, classes registered). The part I am struggling with is passing arrays to a function. How do I do that?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Student // Student class declaration.
{
private:
  string name;
  int id;
  string classes;
  int arraySize;

public:
  void setName(string n)
  {
    name = n;
  }
  void setId(int i)
  {
    id = i;
  }
  void setClasses(string c, int num)
  {
    classes = c;
    arraySize = num;
  }
  string getName()
  {
    return name;
  }
  int getId()
  {
    return id;
  }
  void getClasses()
  {
    for (int counter=0; counter <arraySize; counter++) {

      cout << classes[counter] << endl;
    }

  }

};

int main()
{
  //Student 1
  string s1Name = "John Doe";
  int s1Id = 51090210;
  int const NUMCLASSES1 = 3;
  string s1Classes[NUMCLASSES1] = {"C++","Intro to Theatre","Stagecraft"};
  //Student 2
  string s2Name = "Rick Harambe Sanchez";
  int s2Id = 666123420;
  int const NUMCLASSES2 = 2;
  string s2Classes[NUMCLASSES2] = {"Intro to Rocket Science","Intermediate Acting"};
  //

  Student info;

  info.setName(s1Name);
  info.setId(s1Id);
  //info.setClasses(s1Classes, NUMCLASSES1);
  cout << "Here is Student #1's information:\n";
  cout << "Name: " << info.getName() << endl;
  cout << "ID: " << info.getId() << endl;
  //cout << "Classes: " << info.getClasses() << endl;


  info.setName(s2Name);
  info.setId(s2Id);
  // info.setClasses(s2Classes, NUMCLASSES1);
  cout << "\n\nHere is student #2's information:\n";
  cout << "Name: " << info.getName() << endl;
  cout << "ID: " << info.getId() << endl;
  //cout << "Classes: " << info.getClasses() << endl;



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a beginner, prefer `std:.vector` to raw arrays. Passing a `std::vector` is the same as passing an `int` or `std::string`.

Comment: Where in this code are you trying to pass arrays to functions? You can pass a pointer but then you should also pass a length. You can use `std::array` instead or `vector` as many others suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to pass around variable-length lists in C++ is to use an `std::vector`. A `vector` is a single object that you can easily pass to a function, copying (or referencing) its contents. If you are familiar with Java, it's basically an `ArrayList`. Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class foo {
private:
  vector<string> myStrings;

public:
  void setMyStrings(vector<string> vec) {
    myStrings = vec;
  }
}

//...

foo myObj;
vector<string> list = {"foo","bar","baz"};
myObj.setMyStrings(list);
```

If don't want to use the standard library though, you can pass an array C-style. This involves passing a pointer to the first element of the array, and the length of the array. Example:

```
void processStrings(string* arr, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    string str = arr[i];
    //...
  }
}

string array[] = {"foo","bar","baz"};
processStrings(array, 3); // you could also replace 3 with sizeof(array)
```

Passing raw arrays like this, especially if you wanted to then copy the array into an object, can be painful. ***Raw arrays* in C & C++ are just pointers to the first element of the list.** Unlike in languages like Java and JavaScript, they don't keep track of their length, and you can't just assign one array to another. An `std::vector` encapsulates the concept of a "list of things" and is generally more intuitive to use for that purpose.

Life lesson: use std::vector.

EDIT: See @nathanesau's answer for an example of using constructors to initialize objects more cleanly. (But don't copy-paste, write it up yourself! You'll learn a lot faster that way.)

Answer (score 0):

In the private variables of class Student, you are storing a string:
`String classes;`
where as you should be storing an array of strings like:
`String classes[MAX_NUM_CLASSES];`

then in the set classes function, pass in an array of strings as the first argument, so it should be :

```
void setClasses(string[] c, int num)

{

classes = c; //not sure if simply setting them equal will work, rather copy entire array using a for loop

 arraySize = num;

}
```

This should point you in the right direction

Also, use `std::vector` instead of `string[]`, it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array of `any_data_type` to `function` like this

```
void foo(data_type arr[]);

foo(arr); // If you just want to use the value of array 
foo(&arr); // If you want to alter the value of array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector`. Also, don't add functions you don't need. Here's an example of using `std::vector`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Student // Student class declaration.
{
private:

    vector<string> classes;
    string name;
    int id;

public:

    Student (const vector<string> &classesUse, string nameUse, int idUse) :
        classes (classesUse),
        name    (nameUse),
        id      (idUse)
    {
    }

    void print ()
    {
        std::cout << "Name:    " << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Id:      " << id << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Classes: ";

        for (int i = 0; i < classes.size (); i++)
        {
            if (i < classes.size () - 1)
            {
                std::cout << classes[i] << ", ";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << classes[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Student John ({"C++","Intro to Theatre","Stagecraft"},
                  "John",
                  51090210);

    John.print ();

    Student Rick ({"Intro to Rocket Science","Intermediate Acting"},
                  "Rick",
                  666123420);

    Rick.print ();

    return 0;
}


Name:    John
Id:      51090210
Classes: C++, Intro to Theatre, Stagecraft

Name:    Rick
Id:      666123420
Classes: Intro to Rocket Science, Intermediate Acting
```